# Antivirus doesn't allow to run installed application created using angular 10+ and electron

Tags: angular, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I am facing one issue where I am able to generate exe with the help of electron + angular 10+ and also able to install it. But when i run the installed application it is getting blocked by trend micro antivirus, where in other system the antivirus is not installed that let me use that installed application. I have googled and tried multiple solutions but neither of worked.

Below is my package.json file code

```
  "name": "e-chat-announcement-angular",
  "description": "CLI app",
  "author": "Me me me",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "main.js",
  "build": {
    "appId": "eChatAnnouncement",
    "productName": "ECHATANNOUNCEMENT",
    "files": [
      "**/*",
      "dist/**/*"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "output": "release",
      "buildResources": "dist"
    },
    "asar": false,
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "nsis"
      ],
      "icon": "src/icon.ico",
      "requestedExecutionLevel": "requireAdministrator"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "installerIcon": "src/icon.ico",
      "uninstallerIcon": "src/icon.ico",
      "uninstallDisplayName": "ECHATANNOUNCEMENT",
      "oneClick": false,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "runAfterFinish": true
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "postinstall": "install-app-deps",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "electron-build": "ng build --prod && electron .",
    "electron-package": "electron-packager .  --platform=win32 --arch=x64",
    "start:electron": "ng build --prod --base-href ./ && electron .",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "setup": "electron-builder"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.8",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.8",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.8",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.8",
    "@angular/material": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.8",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.8",
    "custom-electron-titlebar": "^3.2.6",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^10.0.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.13",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "electron": "^11.2.0",
    "electron-builder": "^22.9.1",
    "electron-packager": "^15.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.2",
    "karma": "~5.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

below is my main.js which is used for electron

```
const {app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
// SSL/TSL: this is the self signed certificate support
app.on('certificate-error', (event, webContents, url, error, certificate, callback) => {
  // On certificate error we disable default behaviour (stop loading the page)
  // and we then say "it is all fine - true" to the callback
  event.preventDefault();
  callback(true);
});

const url = require("url");
const path = require("path");

let mainWindow




function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    frame:false,
    
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule:true,
      webSecurity: false
    }
  })

  // new BrowserWindow({ webPreferences: { webSecurity: false } })
 //mainWindow.setMenuBarVisibility= false;


 
  mainWindow.loadURL(
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, `/dist/E-Chat-Announcement-Angular/index.html`),
      protocol: "file:",
      slashes: true
    })
  );
  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
  
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null
  })

  //mainWindow.maximize();
  
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) createWindow()
})
```

It seems I am missing something at configuration part in my application or my be something else,

Below is the Screenshot from antivirus logs

[image]

Let me know if further information is required.

Comment: does your antivirus log which file exactly is the problem? are you able to reproduce this behavior with an electron quickstart built with electron-builder in the default configuration?

Comment: Trend Micro should be stating the alert reason and I assume most likely the reason it's about the app not being sign with a CSC (*Code Signing Cerificate*) so it's from an *untrusted* source.

Comment: @Rhayene I have added error logs at last in question.

Comment: @ChristosLytras Yeah, even I thought of same. May be because of untrusted source. What can be the solution here?

Comment: I would experiment a bit at this stage - maybe you could try to create a self signed certificate and look what the antivirus says, before buying a code signing certificate. If the antivirus changes behavior you would at least know that this is the issue. For electron-builder you configure the signing certificate via environment variables - [code signing docu](https://www.electron.build/code-signing). If you add `forceCodeSigning: true` to your electron-builder configuration you get better feedback if the signing failed (else electron-builder continues without signing)

Comment: Still, since the antivirus does seem to not like the .exe but passes the asar and  resource files, I don't think there is a problem with the content of your app.

Comment: @Rhayene Yeah, i am thinking of doing it with self signed certificate. I tried all possible ways apart from it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the electron-builder package has a history of producing packages that are being [falsely detected as a virus](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues?q=is%3Aissue+virus). This is most likely one of the cases.

I would suggest uploading a demo executable to [virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/) to get a feeling of how widespread the problem is and afterwards [opening an issue](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues) with an example project for reference.

You might also get lucky when trying a beta-release of electron-builder, which you can find on the [release page](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/releases).